# Spring WebMvcTest with post returns 403

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, kotlin

I'm wondering where the issue is with my code, every time I run a post test (irrespective of what controller it targets, or method), I return a 403 error, when in some cases I expect a 401, and in others a 200 response (with auth).

This is a snippet from my controller:

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin("*")
@RequestMapping("/user")
class UserController @Autowired constructor(val userRepository: UserRepository) {
    @PostMapping("/create")
    fun addUser(@RequestBody user: User): ResponseEntity<User> {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(userRepository.save(user))
    }
}
```

And my unit test targeting this controller

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)
@WebMvcTest(UserController::class)
class UserControllerTests {
    @Autowired
    val mvc: MockMvc? = null

    @MockBean
    val repository: UserRepository? = null

    val userCollection = mutableListOf<BioRiskUser>()

    @Test
    fun testAddUserNoAuth() {
        val user = BioRiskUser(
                0L,
                "user",
                "password",
                mutableListOf(Role(
                    0L,
                    "administrator"
                )))
        repository!!
        `when`(repository.save(user)).thenReturn(createUser(user))
        mvc!!
        mvc.perform(post("/create"))
                .andExpect(status().isUnauthorized)
    }

    private fun createUser(user: BioRiskUser): BioRiskUser? {
        user.id=userCollection.count().toLong()
        userCollection.add(user)
        return user
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

As requested, my security config...

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class SecurityConfig(private val userRepository: UserRepository, private val userDetailsService: UserDetailsService) : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {
    @Bean
    override fun authenticationManagerBean(): AuthenticationManager {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean()
    }

    override fun configure(auth: AuthenticationManagerBuilder) {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider())
    }

    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .cors()
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .realmName("App Realm")
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/img/*", "/error", "/favicon.ico", "/doc")
            .anonymous()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .clearAuthentication(true)
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/user")
            .permitAll()
    }

    @Bean
    fun authProvider(): DaoAuthenticationProvider {
        val authProvider = CustomAuthProvider(userRepository)
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService)
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(encoder())
        return authProvider
    }
}
```

and the auth provider

```
class CustomAuthProvider constructor(val userRepository: UserRepository) : DaoAuthenticationProvider() {
    override fun authenticate(authentication: Authentication?): Authentication {
        authentication!!
        val user = userRepository.findByUsername(authentication.name)
        if (!user.isPresent) {
            throw BadCredentialsException("Invalid username or password")
        }
        val result = super.authenticate(authentication)
        return UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, result.credentials, result.authorities)
    }


    override fun supports(authentication: Class<*>?): Boolean {
        return authentication?.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken::class.java) ?: false
    }
}
```

Comment: Please update your question with code that handles authentication and authorization.

Comment: Can you call this endpoint from postman?

Comment: Works fine from Postman (first thing I checked) - I wasn't unit testing initially, but I've started using rest docs, (more to get me into the habit of testing everything, rather than being lazy)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add `@ContextConfiguration(classes=SecurityConfig.class)` to the top of your `UserControllerTests` class after the `@WebMvcTest(UserController::class)` annotation.

Comment: Silly question, doesn't this do away with the point of unit testing? I'm starting to turn it into an integration test (unless my understanding is lacking, which I'm open to).

Comment: With `MockMvc` and the method `mvc.perform()`, you are not writing unit test actually. You are literally making api calls and hence all the configuration is required. If you were to write a unit test for controller, you would stub deeper layers and directly call the Controller’s methods, in your case the `addUser()` method instead of using `MockMvc`.

Answer (score 22):

In my case, the csrf-Protection seems to be still active in my WebMvcTest (even if disabled in your configuration).

So to workaround this, I simply changed my WebMvcTest to something like:

```
    @Test
    public void testFoo() throws Exception {

        MvcResult result = mvc.perform(
                    post("/foo").with(csrf()))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andReturn();

        // ...
    }
```

So the missing `.with(csrf())` was the problem in my case.

Comment: This is the only fix that works for me. Otherwise, when I debug, I see it step through HttpSecurity.csrf().disable() in my config, but then I see it fail in the CrsfFilter.

Comment: The csrf() method comes from this import static org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.request.SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.csrf;

Answer (score 5):

Your problem comes from the CSRF, if you enable debug logging the problem will become obvious, and it comes from the fact that `@WebMvcTest` load only the web layer and not the whole context, **your** `KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` is not loaded.

The loaded config comes from `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.DefaultConfigurerAdapter` (= to `org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`

`WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` contains `crsf()`.

As of today you have 3 options to resolve this:

### Options 1

Create a `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` inside your test class.

The solution suits you if you have only few `@WebMvcTest` annotated class in your project.

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = {MyController.class})
public class MyControllerTest {

    @TestConfiguration
    static class DefaultConfigWithoutCsrf extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            super.configure(http);
            http.csrf().disable();
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

### Options 2

Create a `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` inside a superclass and make your test extend from it.

The solution suits you if you have multiple `@WebMvcTest` annotated class in your project.

```java
@Import(WebMvcTestWithoutCsrf.DefaultConfigWithoutCsrf.class)
public interface WebMvcCsrfDisabler {

    static class DefaultConfigWithoutCsrf extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            super.configure(http);
            http.csrf().disable();
        }
    }
}
```

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = {MyControllerTest .class})
public class MyControllerTest implements WebMvcCsrfDisabler {
    ...
}
```

### Options 3

Use the *spring-security* csrf `SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors`.

This solution is bulky and prone to error, checking for permission denial and forgeting the with(csrf()) will result in false positive test.

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = {MyController.class})
public class MyControllerTest {
    ...
    @Test
    public void myTest() {
        mvc.perform(post("/path")
                .with(csrf()) // <=== THIS IS THE PART THAT FIX CSRF ISSUE
                .content(...)
                
        )
                .andExpect(...);
    }
}
```

Comment: All options you propose have one big disadvantage: they perform test against different setup that production setup. I would like you propose option 4 copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/52211616/2365727

Answer (score 0):

Here's an issue:

```
override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .cors()
        .and()
        .httpBasic()
        .realmName("App Realm")
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/img/*", "/error", "/favicon.ico", "/doc")
        .anonymous()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .logout()
        .invalidateHttpSession(true)
        .clearAuthentication(true)
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/user")
        .permitAll()
}
```

More particularly here:

```
.anyRequest().authenticated()
```

You're requiring for each request to be authenticated, therefore you get 403.

[This tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-integration-tests) explains well how to perform testing with mock user.

The easy way is to have something like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class SecuredControllerRestTemplateIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private val template: TestRestTemplate

    @Test
    fun createUser(): Unit {
        val result = template.withBasicAuth("username", "password")
          .postForObject("/user/create", HttpEntity(User(...)), User.class)
        assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, result.getStatusCode())
    }
}
```

Comment: But I don't want a "full" servlet container up, I shouldn't need one if I'm using the tests correctly(?) or are Spring Boot WebMvcTest flawed? (although I'm also open to the "new hammer" issue)